# Iterate through unordered map C++

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

I have wrote program which reads input until you hit ',' - COMA at the input. Then it counts the number of letters you put in,

I want to iterate through this map but it says that `it` cannot be defined with no type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Type '.' when finished typing keys: " << endl;
    char ch;
    int n = 128;
    std::tr1::unordered_map <char, int> map;

    do{
      ch = _getch();
      cout << ch;
      if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
        map[ch] = map[ch] + 1;
      }
    } while( ch != '.' );

    cout << endl;

    for ( auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it ) //ERROR HERE
      cout << " " << it->first << ":" << it->second;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you compile with `-std=c++11`? `auto` is a C++11 feature.

Comment: Also, please avoid confusion and don't name your objects like STL types, e.g. rename `map` to `aMap`.

Answer (score 37):

With C++17 you can use a shorter, smarter version, like in the code below:

```
unordered_map<string, string> map;
map["hello"] = "world";
map["black"] = "mesa";
map["umbrella"] = "corporation";
for (const auto & [ key, value ] : map) {
    cout << key << ": " << value << endl;
}
```

Comment: Why no uniform initialization and deduction though: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/876ab2ba7e8473b1

Comment: @sehe Just a question. What's the advantage of `auto&&` in your code over `const auto &` in this answer? Also, do you mean 'template argument deduction' when you said 'deduction'?

Comment: @starriet it uses forwarding references, meaning that the arguments could be moved from (and bind as mutable reference to temporaries). It's a bit of a technical habit that I used to have for a while. Since then I have grown to prefer `auto` and `auto const&` explicitly instead. Actually, CTAD is a good point: https://godbolt.org/z/EqjveGfo1

Answer (score 28):

You are using `auto` so you have [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) code. You need a C++11 compliant compiler (e.g. GCC 4.8.2 or newer).
As [Peter G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280314/peter-g) commented, don't name your variable `map` (which is `std::map`) but e.g. `mymap`
So please

```
#include <unordered_map>
```

(no need for `tr1`!)

Then compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g yoursource.cc -o yourprog` and code a [range based for loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for_loop)

```
for (auto it : mymap) 
    std::cout << " " << it.first << ":" << it.second << std::endl;
```

Comment: The last statement should be it.first rather than it->first.

Comment: it's `it.first` and `it.second` since the iterator is automatically dereferenced for you

Comment: If you don't want to copy values, use `auto& it`.

Answer (score 4):

Add `-std=c++11` to your compiler flags (with gcc/icc/clang) if you want to use `auto` (and other C++11 features). Btw, `unordered_map` is in `std` in C++11 ... Also there is `std::isalpha` ...

Answer (score 3):

Based on Dorin Lazăr answer, another possible solution is:

```
unordered_map<string, string> my_map;
my_map["asd"] = "123";
my_map["asdasd"] = "123123";
my_map["aaa"] = "bbb";
for (const auto &element : my_map) {
    cout << element.first << ": " << element.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to change a few more `map` names to `my_map`.

Comment: Sorry, fixing it now.

Comment: Which has the better performance between Erik's solution `for (const auto &e: my_map)` and Basile's one `for (auto e: my_map)`?